# Conan package manager: Using resource files in unit tests with

Tags: unit-testing, resource-files, conan

I have a Conan/CMake project which has some unit tests written in Catch2. Here's the project hierarchy:

```
├── conanfile.py
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── ...
├── src
│   └── ...
└── test
    └── resources
        ├── resource1.xml
        └── ...
    └── src
        └── unit_test1.cpp
        └── ...
```

In the unit tests, I want to read from the resource files, for example:

```
readFile("test/resources/resource1.xml");
```

The resources files only have to be available to the unit tests. They are of no use to the final product application.

Also, I want to run the unit tests in the build step of `conanfile.py` so that the build fails when the unit tests fail. So `conanfile.py` looks like this (the last line runs the tests):

```
class TestConan(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    generators = "cmake"
    build_requires = "catch2/2.2.1@bincrafters/stable"
    exports_sources = "CMakeLists.txt", "include*", "src*", "test/src*", "test/resources*"

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

        self.run(os.sep.join(["bin", "unitTests"]))
```

This works, but only if the resources are in a `test/resources` directory relative to where the unit test binary is executed. This is also hard-coded in the unit test sources. Also note the 
 `"test/resources*"` is required in `export_sources` in `conanfile.py`.

I wonder if there is a more elegant or standard way to make resource file available to the unit tests.

Comment: So your main concern here is that you are "exporting" the tests sources and resources too into the package recipe? But this totally makes sense, because such a build & test will also happen if someone fires a ``conan install --build``, and it will need the files to be there. Of course, there could be other ways, like an env-var containing the paths to the external resource files. Or maybe another build_require that just store the resource files? I would need to know more about your use case, maybe it is better for discussion to move the issue to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Comment: Ok, I was missing the point here. I agree now it makes sense to export the resource files with the package. I was also wondering if there is some standard way for handling resource files for unit tests. But I guess that's not even a Conan-related question.